# How to configure Parse Server with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Actually, I have Installed the necessary software but I couldn't able to pass this step!!! Please, anyone, help me with this...

Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...{ [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\Indium Software.mongodb\versions\mongodb-4.0.8-windows-64' -> 'C:\Users\Indium Software.mongodb\versions\mongodb-current']
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'symlink',

This is what the error I have received...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running cmd.exe with elevated permissions? Try to run cmd.exe as administrator under windows and then run your command again. Hopefully this solves the issue.